# Detect why a Form "disappears"?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

In a large old application I have to fix, I have two forms, like in the image (that is a Notepad example)

[image]

When I leave (with mouse cursor) my small(Y) form's area, that form will "disappear", some like I'd clicked on the big form and activated it.

But I didn't click on X, neither the X caption is active, however the small Y form goes backward and is not visible anymore.

How to track the problem?

Any of `Resize`, `Activated`, `Deactivate`, `LostFocus`, `GotFocus`, `GiveFeedback`, `MdiChildActivate` is not tracked on any of both forms when I leave the `Y` area...

Comment: Can it be `MouseLeave` on Y form or `MouseEnter` on X form?

Comment: Evidently there are a `MouseLeave` event, but normally it does not hide the active form...

Comment: Normally no, but if you have on X form: `public MouseEnter(...) { this.BringToFront(); }` it can be a problem. I'm guessing, nothing else to work with ;)

Comment: any MouseEnter logic is not implemented on the X form, nor MouseLeave on Y form...

Comment: Which events are catched in forms X and Y?

Comment: @Marco, a lot of events, but I stressed the most important where I set the tracking breackpoints. Why this question?

Comment: You stressed the most important but you were incorrect. -1 for posting a question with misleading/inaccurate diagnostic info.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override [OnVisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onvisiblechanged.aspx) of form Y and set a breakpoint on this. During debugging reproduce the situation and check property Form.Visible on false and check than the Call Stack.

Comment: the form is always visible just goes to back, because if I minimize the X I can see the Y.

Answer (score 1):

It's a system-wide thing as I know; I think it's called **[active window tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957204.aspx)**.

Might want to try disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Making multiple tests I identified the problem: The **`Y`** Form were `Deactivate`d by the **`X`**, because on the `MouseMove` event on `X` produced a Focus() on a specific control inside the (X) form...

Thanks to everybody for help!

(PS. So, I was wrong in the initial post about the Deactivate event)

Answer (score 0):

You might set form 'Y' TopMost property to 'True' This way it never disappears behind 'X'. (provided the 'Topmost' property of 'X' is NOT true.